# JSON array, how to get index of the object with higher value of the given attribute?

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs, sorting

I have following JSON array of the objects:

```
    var dummyData = [
        {
            hr:"10",
            dial_success_rate:"23",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"11",
            dial_success_rate:"24",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"12",
            dial_success_rate:"25",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"13",
            dial_success_rate:"26",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"14",
            dial_success_rate:"27",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"15",
            dial_success_rate:"28",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"16",
            dial_success_rate:"29",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"17",
            dial_success_rate:"30",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"18",
            dial_success_rate:"45",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"19",
            dial_success_rate:"40",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"20",
            dial_success_rate:"39",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"21",
            dial_success_rate:"55",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"22",
            dial_success_rate:"12",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
        {
            hr:"23",
            dial_success_rate:"9",
            appt_success_rate:"60",
            appt_100_numbers:"10",
        },
    ];
```

I would like to get index of the object with highest value on the given attribute.

It means something like this:

```
 $scope.getHigherItem = function(data, stat, info) {
        var selectedValues = data.map(function(x) {
            return parseFloat(x[stat]);
        });

        var i = selectedValues.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, selectedValues));

        var result = {};
        info.forEach(function(x) {
            result[x] = data[i][x];
        });
        return result;
    };




 console.log($scope.getHigherItem(dummyData, "dial_success_rate", ["dial_success_rate"]));
```

Example above is returning higher value, but is not returning index of the object in the array.

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: you want to find the index of the max value of the `selectedValues` ?

Comment: Yes, i want to find index of the object with highest value on the given attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add an attribute to the result which contain the index like following :

```
...
var result = {};
/*
info.forEach(function(x) {
    result[x] = data[i][x];
});*/

result[stat] = data[i][stat]; // <-- INSTEAD OF FOREACH LOOP
result.index = i; // <-- HERE
return result;
```

Comment: Other thing, you don't need the foreach loop either

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxValue = Math.max(selectedValues);
var maxIndexes = []; //Array of indexes of == maxValue

for (_i = 0, _len = selectedValues.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  a = selectedValues[i];
  if (a === max) {
    maxIndexes.push(_i);
  }
}

...
...
return {
  result: result
  maxIndexes: maxIndexes

}
```

With that you have an array which contains the indexes of all the objects on your selectedValues array that are equal to max. If you want the first of this just do `maxIndexes[0]`

Comment: A one liner for maxIndeces `var maxIndeces = selectedValues.reduce(function(a,b,idx,array){if(array[idx]===maxValue){ a.push(array[idx]);}; return a;},[])`

Comment: @klode nice use of reduce

Answer (score 0):

Do all at once in the map-function:

```
    var getHigherItem = function (data, stat) {
        var compare, result = {};

        var selectedValues = data.map(function (x, i) {                
            if (i == 0) {
                compare = parseFloat(x[stat]);
            } else if(compare < parseFloat(x[stat])){
                compare = parseFloat(x[stat]);
                result[stat] = parseFloat(x[stat]);
                result['index'] = i;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };

    console.log(getHigherItem(dummyData, "dial_success_rate"));
```